# Data normalization

Tags: data-transformation, normalization

Hello,
I want to eliminate the effect of a parameter over another parameter. Let's say, we are using a,b,c parameters to calculate x. and the trend of x is very similar to b. I want to nullify this effect. Am I thinking in the right direction? Is there any other way than dividing x with b?

Comment: Could you give us more information? Why do you want to remove it? What do you mean by removing it? How are you going to use those variables (what model)?

Comment: Common terminology is that you ["control for $b.$"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22control+for%22)